# How to remove headers in an array

Tags: php, zend-framework, header, http-headers

All,

I have a PHP application that seems to generate the following headers in an array. I wish to remove these headers, so I can set new ones like the one for a pdf download.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "Content-type: text/html"
}
```

How do I do this, as this doesn't seem to work:

```
var_dump(headers_list());

header_remove("X-Powered-By");
header_remove("Content-type");

var_dump(headers_list());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lines may do the same what you exactly want to do.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.pdf"');
readfile('/var/www/sample.pdf');
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems to work, but instead of asking the user to save the file, it prints the pdf contents in the browser. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify headers, if no output has been sent to the client yet. Thus var_dump function will cause header_remove to be ignored (since it obviously outputs text to the client).

You should also take a look out output buffering functions:
https://www.php.net/outcontrol